# Reference for nonlinear inequalities - tools and tricks

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, reference-request

I am searching for good references (online tutorials, papers and/or books) about nonlinear inequalities of the form

$$
f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \,\, f(x) \leq 0 \,.
$$

In especially what are common tools or tricks for can be used for solving different classes of these kind of inequalities. Also good collections of examples/exercises with solutions would be appreciated.

Info: I am already aware of SOS decomposition techniques.

Comment: let $a(x)\leq b(x)$ with $a,b:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary inequality in $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. then obviously $a-b$ is a candidate for $f$. I think your question is much to broad. Are there any further restrictions?

Comment: @Max I am not searching for candidates for $f$. The function $f$ is given and I am trying to show whether it holds true or not. Also I do not think this question is too broad since it is tagged as reference request. Other questions under this tag just ask for books about, e.g. differential equations which is also very broad. I am looking for references on nonlinear inequalities and methods/systematic approaches to deal with them.